# What is in Object.__proto__?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototype, v8, proto

In Google Chrom's javascript, objects have a property named `__proto__` that points to their prototype (or parent) object.

```
var foo = {};
console.log(foo.__proto__ === Object.prototype);    //returns true
```

However, this is **not true** for the `Object` object.

```
console.log(Object.__proto__ === Object.prototype);    //returns false
```

The `Object.__proto__` property appears to be an empty method

```
> console.log(Object.__proto__.toString());
function () {}
```

Beyond serving as a warning story about relying on javascript features that start outside standard bodies -- what is the `Object.__proto__` function?

Comment: `Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype` ...Object is a function. `typeof Object === "function"`

Comment: Have you read through this document? It might clear up some things. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: ...and `__proto__` was added to ECMAScript 6.

Comment: ...and the reason `Function.prototype` appears to be an empty function is that many of the prototypes of the built-in constructors are actually an instance of the object they construct. For example, `Array.isArray(Array.prototype); // true` (Or maybe not quite an instance, but they have some relationship back to the constructor.)

Comment: @squint, ...and `Function.__proto__===Function.prototype`

Comment: Ah, thank you @squint.  `Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype` being true and `Object.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype` being true cleared this up for me.  I've always assumed `Object` and `Function` were at the same hierarchy level, and that `Object`'s prototype was `Object.prototype`.   If you wanted to add some version of your comment as an answer I'm happy to mark it as best.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm too tired to put together a decent answer, so feel free to gather together what I wrote and whatever else you've figured out, and post an answer instead.

Comment: Thanks again @squint -- done and below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [squint's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/squint) comments above, I've been able to get to the bottom of this.  My unstated, incorrect (and 10+ year) assumption was that the global `Object` helper object's prototype object was also the top level "prototype of prototypes" at the top/end of javascript's prototype chain.  This is not true.

The `Object` helper object and the `Function` helper object both have the same parent prototype-object

```
console.log( Object.__proto__ === Function.__proto__ );    //true
```

So, the reason `Object.__proto__` points to an empty function is -- that empty function **is** its prototype object for the `Object` object.  If you want to get to the prototype of prototypes from `Object` (without using `.prototype`), you need to dig back a bit further.

```
console.log( Object.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype );         //true
```

I also put together a quick diagram that maps out the real prototypes of a few of Javascript's lower level helper/constructor objects.

[image]

Finally -- I also also discovered Google Chrome has implemented the `Reflect` object, [which includes a `getPrototypeOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/getPrototypeOf), which appears to be the same as the `Object.getPrototypeOf` method.

Comment: Re: down-voters -- if something above is incorrect, please let me know.  If it's correct but you dislike my point of view -- I guess I'll live with the downvotes ;)

Comment: I think you're right, but the graph is confusing because I'd expect the arrows to be pointing the other direction (the direction of inheritance). And this sentence is confusing: *"The Object helper object shares its prototype with the Function helper object."* The phrasing is vague. I can't tell when you're talking about the constructor functions, their `.prototype` or the object from which they inherit (which is accessible via `__proto__`). So that may be part of the reason for the DVs.

Comment: The `getPrototypeOf` is new with the `Reflect` object, but it has been around for quite a while via `Object.getPrototypeOf`. At least I *think* they're the same. Haven't really looked too much at `Reflect` yet. EDIT: I see on the docs that they are indeed the same. Good.

Comment: Changed the wording to be clearer, and updated the diagram to have the arrows pointing back towards the top of the hierarchy.  Also, FWIW, most docs lack of clarity about the `.prototype` property and an object's true "parent object prototype" are what led to this question in the first place.   Thanks again for the help @squint!

Comment: How does `Array instanceof Object allow true` if `instanceof` checks the prototype chain? In the chart Object (helper) is not in the prototype chain of Array (helper)

Answer (score 10):

The top of the object graph is formed to maintain as much consistency with the expectations set elsewhere in the spec.

Necessarily, there comes a point where normal object linkages cannot be used because you "run out of objects".

A basic understanding of JavaScript leads us to expect the `[[Prototype]]` of `Object` to be the prototype property of the function used to create the `Object` function-object.

We expect `Function`s to be created using the `Function` function-object, so...

```
Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype
```

Because we are at the top of the object graph and want to maintain consistency of expected behavior we configure the `[[Prototype]]` of `Function` to be `Function.prototype`.

```
Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype
```

Thus ensuring `Function instanceof Function === true`.

We can show that `Function.prototype` is a special function-object because:

```
Function.prototype.prototype === undefined
```

...and every user-defined function (other than fat-arrows) has an object on its prototype property.

Because of all the above:

```
Object.__proto__ === Function.__proto__
```

This may might look odd, but as previously noted, at the top of the object graph we have a limited set of candidate objects to point to.

TC-39 now needed to identify what the `[[Prototype]]` of the `[[Prototype]]` of `Object` was. 
Per the above we know that the `[[Prototype]]` of `Object` is `Function.prototype`.

In some sense we are now above `Function.prototype` in the object graph, so a special `Object` instance (the "prototype object") was chosen to be this value.

This means that the top of every prototype chain can be conveniently tied up with `Object.prototype`.

This of course, also meets the desireable requirement that everything "is an object".

```
Object.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

At this point we need to complete the object graph, so we set the `[[Prototype]]` of `Object.prototype` to be `null`.

```
Object.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === null
```

Comment: Useful information @BenAston -- thank you! but I'm not sure the `Object.__proto__` information is correct?  `Object.__proto__.toString()` returns `"function () {}"` -- i.e. an empty function, **not** a `[native code]` function (Chrome, OS X El Cap)?  Re: outside standard bodies, my statement/snark was unclear.  It's my understanding __proto__ was implemented in browsers despite it not being a part of an ES standard, and was only recently incorporated into the ES6 standard.

Comment: The rendering of `Object.__proto__.toString()` will depend on the version of your browser. Also: you want `toString` to print out the C++ source code? If you don't believe me: tell me what user-land function created the built-in `Object` function-object?

Comment: The reason I'm not sure your description is 100% accurate is, if I log a function with native code in Chrome's browser, (or use the toString method), I get something that mentions the [native code] (`function split() { [native code] }`.  However, when Chrome (or `.toString`) renders the `Object.__proto__` object, it does not include the native code and looks like an empty user land function (`function() {}`)

Comment: Downvoter, please explain! If I'm wrong, please explain how so I can learn from my mistake.

Comment: Down-voted for the incorrect information about "Native Code" functions.  Down-vote removed now that that's gone.

Answer (score 1):

[Alan Storm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40937809/9649450) seems could use the following modifications:

1. Delete the 3rd node of 2nd column of the digram, which is
   misleading: `Array.__proto__` is not the "Array Object's
   Prototype" but the same as `Function.__proto__` (`Array.__proto__ === Function.__proto__` is `true`)
2. Make Array Contructor point to it's true prototype, which is
   `Function.__proto__`
   The diagram should look like something like this:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Fko.png