# Why __proto__ not the object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, babeljs

I put the following code to babel:

```
class Animal {}

class Rabbit extends Animal {}
```

And it transpiles it to the following:

```
"use strict";

function _inheritsLoose(subClass, superClass) {
  subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass.prototype);
  subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
  subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}

var Animal = function Animal() {};

var Rabbit =
  /*#__PURE__*/
  function(_Animal) {
    _inheritsLoose(Rabbit, _Animal);

    function Rabbit() {
      return _Animal.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }

    return Rabbit;
  }(Animal);
```

The question is why does it use this line `subClass.__proto__ = superClass;` and according to docs `__proto__` could be either object or null but here `superClass` is a function.

My question is not duplicate since, I'm not asking about object.prototype=function.prototype, but why `__proto__ = typeof function` instead of `object` or `null` as in spec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is in Object.\_\_proto\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920909/what-is-in-object-proto)

Comment: Probably for static properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for *static properties / methods*. They are also inherited:

```
 class Animal {
   static test() { }
 }

 console.log(Rabbit.test());
```

Now to transpile that correctly, the `Rabbit` constructor function has to inherit the `Animal` constructor function. That is usually no problem, as **functions are objects too** and therefore can inherit each other. Unfortunately, there is no way to create a function that inherits another, that has to be set afterwards:

```
 function Animal () { }
 Animal.test = function() { }

 function Rabbit() { }

 Object.setPrototypeOf(Rabbit, Animal);

 console.log(Rabbit.test());
```

Now the next problem is, that `Object.setPrototypeOf` is quite new, just as `class`, so to transpile it down it can't be used. Thats where the `.__proto__` property comes into play: It was once added by Chrome to change the prototype of an object, and as a lot of libraries adopted the usage, other browsers implemented it too and it was also added to the spec, although it is considered a design mistake (performance nightmare). It is the only reliable way to transpile static class properties down by now.

In the future the browser support for `class` gets hopefully better and we don't have to rely on these transpilation hacks anymore.